# IntelliJ not finding individual tests in scalatest FlatSpec

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I am running IntelliJ.  I have a test suite that extends `FlatSpec` like

```
class MyTest extends FlatSpec {

  val foo = Seq(1, 2, 3)
  foo.foreach { x => println(x) }

  it should "run test 1" in {
     println("foo")
  }
  it should "run test 2" in {
     println("bar")
  }
}
```

For some reason the line with the block `foo.foreach { x => println(x)}` is preventing IntelliJ from discovering the individual tests in the suite like "run test 1".

If I comment this line out, IntelliJ finds the individual tests.

What's the root cause here?

IntelliJ community edition, 2021.2.3

Comment: Using `it` for the first test looks odd, try using a `String`.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? `Help | About` If possible please prepare and provide a small reproducible project sample. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think I identified the trigger and clarified in a minimal example above, along with version number